# Change a cell to a specific colour in excel if a value comes from a different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have an excel sheet and in one sheet I have the location of different work sites that are worked at and in 5 subsequent sheets I have different jobs to track employee hours. I would like to know if there's any way to change the colour of the cell in the "work site" sheet depending on which "job" sheet the figure came from. I don't want to change the cell colour based on the value but based on which sheet it came from.

Comment: colours can be managed mostly by macro, and a bit by rules, but in order to help you we need exact sheets schema reference.

Comment: @Mark In each job work sheet I just have a date column and a simple sum function for each day to total hours worked by staff and then I transfer that sum to whichever work site those hours relate to. However, since a job may be done on one site one day then the next day a different job may be done on the same site. It would be nice to be able to differentiate what job was done by colour rather than selecting the value and seeing which sheet it came from via the formula bar, so each job would have a different colour reference.

Comment: pls upload here a simple empty xlsx file with this schema.

Comment: @Mark Here is a link to a blank version https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ai0G1fQE071mhEFS-f1b65KYf3yB